# How do I make a sub class return a less general typedef in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance, design-patterns

Disclaimer: I appreciate that the following might not be the correct way to do things, and would appreciate suggestions on how I might do things correctly.

I have the following `typedef`.

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexProperties, boost::no_property, GraphProperties> Witness;
```

and the following function in my `Solver` interface.

```
virtual Witness solve(const Graph& graph) = 0;
```

My intention is that a `Witness` will be the (abstract) return type of `Solver.solve()`. I would like to implement classes that inherit from Solver and implement their own versions of the function `solve()`. One such class will be a `SpecialSolver : public Solver`. This `SpecialSolver` should return something more specialised than a `Witness`, say, a `SpecialWitness`. So, the implementation of `solve()` in `SpecialSolver` should look something like the following.

```
Witness SpecialSolver::solve(const Graph& graph)
{
    SpecialWitness Special;

    // Do some stuff

    return Special;
}
```

My knowledge of templates in C++ is not good. I initially thought that I could do something like this:

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, SpecialVertexProperties, boost::no_property, SpecialGraphProperties> SpecialWitness;
```

where `SpecialVertexProperties : VertexProperties` and `SpecialGraphProperties : GraphProperties`. Then, `SpecialWitness` would be a sub type of Witness and I would achieve my desired result. Alas, this is not correct, and I am wondering what the correct design would instead be? How can I make a `SpecialWitness` a specialised form of `Witness`, so that I can write the clients of all implementations `Solver`, simple to the solver interface?

Comment: semiofftopic: your wording is a tiny bit odd,  "returning a typedef" does not make too much sense. `Witness` is just an alias, a different name, but the actual type you return is still that `boost::adjacency_list`

Comment: if you are returning a value it must have exactly same type. If you would return `std::unique_ptr<Witness>` then you can return pointer to sub-classes without problem.

Comment: Whether `SpecialWitness` is a subtype of `Witness` depends on how `boost::adjacency_list` is implemented, and it would be fiendishly difficult to to that. I can't glance it from [the implementation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp) so they might have somehow done it, but I doubt this was one of the requirements when `boost::adjacency_list` was written. In short, I doubt this is fixable solely by returning a pointer (or reference) to allow polymorphism.

Answer (score 4):

It won't work that way, you'll get victim of an effect called *'object slicing'*:

At the time you return your object, everything that made `SpecialWitness` special is cut off and only the base class `Witness` parts remain.

If you want to return polymorphically, there's no way around references or pointers; as you create objects within your function, you'll opt for pointers to dynamically allocated objects.

Now to prevent memory leaks right from the start, you'd use smart pointers (won't even show the raw pointer variant...):

```
std::unique_ptr<Witness> SpecialSolver::solve(const Graph& graph)
{
    auto special = std::make_unique<SpecialWitness>();

    // Do some stuff

    return special;
}
```

Finally, though, have a close look at the `Witness` base class!

Is it intended to be inherited from at all (i. e. does it provide a virtual destructor – and it doesn't [seem](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html) so!)? If not, you'll be in trouble when trying to delete your objects. Then aggregating is the better way to go:

```
class Witness
{
    boost::adjacency_list<...> m_aList;
public:
    virtual ~Witness() = default;

    // provide some appropriate interface...
};
```

Edit: How would inheritance look like?

```
class Witness
{
public:
    virtual ~Witness() = default;

    virtual void doSomething() { /* ... */ } // virtual allows to override
    virtual void doSomethingElse() = 0;      // pure virtual, no implementation
                                             // in base class

// to allow the derived class to access the adjacency list, it might be more
// meaningful to make it protected (but that depends on your specific needs)
protected:
    boost::adjacency_list<...> m_aList;
};
```

Now as we have at least one pure virtual function (this is not a necessity, in many cases, it doesn't make sense to provide an implementation in the base class, though, then we'd leave it to the deriving classes to provide one), we created an *abstract* class. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated (i. e. you cannot create objects of), only the non-abstract derived classes can.

```
class SpecialWitness : public Witness
{
public:
    // you inherit already virtual destructor, so you don't need to specify
    // explicitly...

    void doSomething() override    // you CAN override, if this is meaningful
    { /* ... */ } 
    void doSomethingElse() override // if you don't override, the class will                                         
    { /* ... */ }                   // remain abstract (possible; if meaningful
                                    // is up to you to decide...) 
};
```

Comment: Making `Witness` an interface (pure virtual) can be a good move.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. So that I can fully understand, could you expand on what you would have in the place of ... as the template parameter of m_aList. Also, could you quickly sketch out how the class SpecialWitness would look? Thanks.

Comment: I understand your suggestion up to "Finally, though, have a close look at the Witness base class!". SpecialWitness is should be a sub type of Witness, but the type of m_aList is not clear to me. What is this interface doing, also?

Comment: @jx template parameters are exactly the same as you have in your question (just have been lazy and didn't repeat them...). For `SpecialWitness` I added a few lines. The point is that you pack the adjacency list into a wrapper class providing the necessary features (virtuality) so that it can be used as polymorphic base class (which the boost class didn't). The public interface of the class is up to you to define. What shall the `Witness` class be able to do? Which functions will you need for? That depends entirely on you.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I understand why this is a better solution, but just have one question: I needed the template parameters for SpecialWitness adjacency list to be different to the template parameters for Witness. As it stands, they are the same type, but I want, for example, a GraphProperties as the last template argument in Witness, but SpecialGraphPropeties as the last template parameter in SpecialWitness :)

Comment: Problem is that instantiations of templates with different parameters are entirely unrelated classes, just as if you wanted to have a base class with a member of type `int`, but let the derived class replace it with `double`. Not supported in C++. In this situation I'd consider `Witness` base class not to provide any member variables at all and instead to have two different deriving classes (i. e. instead of parent and child have siblings), each one having an appropriate template instantiation as member. Possibly you could implement the deriving classes as templates as well.

Answer (score 0):

> My intention is that a Witness will be the (abstract) return type of Solver.solve()

It cannot be an *abstract* return type, since abstract types cannot be instantiated and thus not returned.

Covariant return type is only possible with indirection - either a pointer or a reference.  This doesn't quite work well when you intend to create the object within the function.

Furthermore, covariance requires that the specialised type is inherited from the generic type.

> Then, SpecialWitness would be a sub type of Witness and I would achieve my desired result. Alas, this is not correct

To clarify what is not correct: It would **need** to be a subclass, but `boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, SpecialVertexProperties, boost::no_property, SpecialGraphProperties>` **would not** be a sub class of `boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexProperties, boost::no_property, GraphProperties>` (presumably), so it is not a valid type for covariant return type.

---

> I am wondering what the correct design would instead be?

It depends on what you're trying to achieve.

For example, if the runtime polymorphism is not essential, then you could use templates throughout, let the return type be templated and there would be no need for covariance.

If you do need runtime polymorphism, then I suspect that a decent soltion would be  use the same `GraphProperties` type throughout, and use type-erasure techniques to allow the instances created by children to have different behaviour.